# If and else if synatax

Tags: java, if-statement

Is this

```
if (score >= 93)
 grade = "A";
if (score >= 84 && score <= 92)
 grade = "B";
if (score >= 75 && score <= 83)
 grade = "C";
if (score < 75)
 grade = "F";
```

the same as this

```
if (score>= 93)
 grade = "A";
else if (score >= 84)
 grade = "B";
else if (score >= 75)
 grade = "C";
else 
 grade = "F";
```

I think they are both different because for the bottom one, if somebody has a score of 95 it is greater than 84 and 75. Which means the grade will be A, B, and C. The first `if` statement gives a restriction on the upper and lower bound of the `score` so there can be only one `grade` per `score`.

Comment: these 2 codes are absolutely the same

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see for yourself?

Comment: @Lashane whether they're the same depends on the type of `score`.

Comment: @DavidWallace can you elaborate it further? score here either byte or int or long, what will be the difference?

Comment: What if it's `float` or `double`?

Comment: @DavidWallace then second if will work better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two pieces of code happen to produce the same result because your conditions do not overlap. Each condition is checking a specific range of values for `score`.

However, the following two segments of code would produce different results.

```
if (a > 5) {
   System.out.println("a is greater than 5");
}
if (a > 3) {
   System.out.println("a is greater than 3");
}
```

Given a=10, that code would produce: "a is greater than 5" and "a is greater than 3".

But with this code:

```
if (a > 5) {
   System.out.println("a is greater than 5");
}
else if (a > 3) {
   System.out.println("a is greater than 3");
}
```

Given a=10, that code would only produce: "a is greater than 5".

Answer (score 2):

These *logically* are the same in your example.

When an `if` is true in an `if-else` block, all the subsequent elses are skipped.

Comment: This is correct if `score` is an integral type, and wrong if it's `float` or `double`.  The OP never specified.

Answer (score 1):

The *result* from your two examples will be the same.

The difference in actual execution is that in your first example at least 4 and up to 6 comparisons will be made regardless of the value held in `score`.

In your second example as soon as an expression yields `true` none of the subsequent comparisons are made.